# Cisco ASA Determine static NAT programmatically?

Tags: firewall, cisco, cisco-asa, snmp

Is it possible to determine the static nats on an ASA 5550 or 5540 running 8.2(x) programmatically?  I don't see it as an available SNMP oid but perhaps I am missing it.

Comment: what exactly do you want programatically?  The list of NAT entries?  Is screen-scraping an option?

Comment: I would like the output of "show run static".  Screen scraping is less preferred but if that's the only way to get the info....

Comment: What system are you feeding this into?

Comment: A homegrown IPAM to handle our large number of NATs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is probably a more graceful way, but you could write an [expect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect) script to login to your ASA and then run the command `sh run static`, capture the output and then send it somewhere for processing.

I haven't got a full script that will do exactly what you need, as I only use expect to roll out configuration changes across the ASAs I manage.  However, the following will login to an ASAs and get to the enable (#) prompt, then dump the config to a tftp server and exit.  That does get your config onto a server where you can then process the file(s) using grep.

```
spawn ssh {user}@{asa-hostname-or-ip-address}
expect -timeout 10
expect "assword:"
send "{password}\r"
expect ">"
send "en\r"
expect "assword:"
send "{password}\r"
expect "#"

# save the running config to the location configured under tftp-server
send "write net\r"
expect "#"

# logout of the ASA
send "exit\r"
```

Replace {username}, {asa-hostname-or-ip-address}, and {password} above as appropriate.

Someone who is more experienced in expect than me might be able to extract the output of the `sh run static` command using `$expect_out(buffer)` and then process it, but the above should get you some of the way.

If doing this on a bunch of ASAs you can put the above into a bash script that pulls in an array of asa hostnames, usernames and passwords, then loop using `do`.

Comment: While not graceful, it does work.